# order statistics with Bernoulli variables

Tags: order-statistics

$X$ and $Y$ are iid Bernoulli($p$), then what's the marginal pmf and joint pmf for $\max(X, Y)$ and $\min(X, Y)$?

Not sure if I can use the formula for marginal order statistics pmf here.

Comment: Hint: $(X,Y)$ can have four different values. Make a table with four rows and five columns. On each row, write the values of $X$, $Y$,the probability that $(X,Y)$ has these values (sub-hint: iid Bernoulli$(p)$ might help), $\max(X,Y)$, and $\min(X,Y)$. Stare very hard at the array that you have created.

Comment: I do not know what you call *the formula for marginal order statistics pmf* but you could simply enumerate the values of $(i,j)$ such that the event $[\max(X,Y)=i,\min(X,Y)=j]$ is not empty and compute its probability.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U=\min(X,Y)$, $V =\max(X,Y)$. Since $U \leqslant V$, possible values of the pair $(U,V)$ are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$. You now have to compute these probabilities:
$$
   \mathbb{P}(U=0,V=0) \stackrel{\text{why?}}{=} \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0) = \underline{\phantom{1-p}}^2
$$
$$
   \mathbb{P}(U=1,V=1) \stackrel{\text{why?}}{=} \mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1) = \underline{\phantom{p}}^2
$$
$$
   \mathbb{P}(U=0,V=1) \stackrel{\text{why?}}{=} 1 -  \mathbb{P}(U=0,V=0) - \mathbb{P}(U=1,V=1)
$$
To compute marginals, apply the definition, e.g.:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(U=0) = \mathbb{P}(U=0,V=0) + \mathbb{P}(U=0,V=1)
$$
etc.